# Salesforce Code Coverage Failure. Your code coverage is 12%. You need at least 75% coverage to complete this deployment

Tags: salesforce, code-coverage, apex, salesforce-development, salesforce-developer

I wanted to deploy my code to production. In this apex code, I am calling a third party api for opportunity on click of button which triggers the doSomething() from VF page. I want to fix this issue and push the below code to my production account.
Here is my apex class code

```
{
    private ApexPages.StandardController standardController;
 
    public DetailButtonController(ApexPages.StandardController standardController)
    {
         
        this.standardController = standardController;
    }
 
    public PageReference doSomething()
    {
        // Apex code for handling record from a Detail page goes here
        Id recordId = standardController.getId();
        Opportunity record = (Opportunity) standardController.getRecord();
        
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
    Http http = new Http();
    req.setEndpoint('https://mergeasy.com/merge_file');
    req.setMethod('POST');
    
    //function to Convert date to mm/dd/yyy
    Date dToday = record.Closing_Date__c;
    String clos_date =  'On or before ' + dToday.month() + '/' + dToday.day() + '/' + dToday.year();
    
    Date dAcc = record.Offer_Acceptance_Date__c;
    String acc_date = dAcc.month() + '/' + dAcc.day() + '/' + dAcc.year();
    
    String str1 = '' + record.Purchase_Price__c ;
    String f_p_price = str1.SubStringBefore('.');
    
    String str2 = '' + record.Escrow_Deposit__c ;
    String e_d_price = str2.SubStringBefore('.');
    
    String str3 = '' + record.Balance__c ;
    String b_price = str3.SubStringBefore('.'); 
      
    
    if(record.Second_Seller_Name_Phone__c==null && record.Second_Seller_Email__c==null && record.Name!=null && record.Company_Profile__c!=null){
        req.setBody('seller_name='+record.Name+'&buyer_name='+record.Company_Profile__c+'&county='+record.County_Contract__c+'&street_address='+record.Left_Main__Address_1__c+'&p_price='+f_p_price+'&escrow_deposit='+e_d_price+'&title_agent='+record.Escrow_Agent_Name__c+'&title_address='+record.Escrow_Address__c+'&title_phone='+record.Escrow_Number__c+'&balance='+b_price+'&accept_date='+acc_date+'&closing_date='+clos_date+'&inspection_days='+record.Inspection_Days__c+'&special_clause='+record.Special_Clauses__c+'&doc_id=XXXXXXXXXX&doc_name=Contract.pdf&delivery_method=docusign&sign_order=true&recipient1_email='+record.Email__c+'&recipient1_name='+record.Name+'&recipient2_name='+record.Company_Profile__c+'&recipient2_email=developer.c2c@gmail.com&docusign_doc_name=Contract - Attorney Involved&email_subject=Contract:'+record.Left_Main__Address_1__c+'&email_body=Hi please sign the attached contract');
    }
    
    else if(record.Second_Seller_Name_Phone__c!=null && record.Second_Seller_Email__c!=null && record.Name!=null && record.Company_Profile__c!=null){
        String name = record.Name + ' and ' + record.Second_Seller_Name_Phone__c ;
        req.setBody('seller_name='+name+'&buyer_ame='+record.Company_Profile__c+'&county='+record.County_Contract__c+'&street_address='+record.Left_Main__Address_1__c+'&p_price='+f_p_price+'&escrow_deposit='+e_d_price+'&title_agent='+record.Escrow_Agent_Name__c+'&title_address='+record.Escrow_Address__c+'&title_phone='+record.Escrow_Number__c+'&balance='+b_price+'&accept_date='+acc_date+'&closing_date='+clos_date+'&inspection_days='+record.Inspection_Days__c+'&special_clause='+record.Special_Clauses__c+'&doc_id=XXXXXXXXXX&doc_name=Contract.pdf&delivery_method=docusign&sign_order=true&recipient1_email='+record.Email__c+'&recipient1_name='+record.Name+'&recipient2_name='+record.Second_Seller_Name_Phone__c+'&recipient2_email='+record.Second_Seller_Email__c+'&recipient3_email=developer.c2c@gmail.com&recipient3_name='+record.Company_Profile__c+'&docusign_doc_name=Contract - Normal(1S1B).pdf&email_subject=Contract:'+record.Left_Main__Address_1__c+'&email_body=Hi please sign the attached contract');
    }
    
    req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXX'); 
 try {
        res = http.send(req);
    } catch(System.CalloutException e) {
        System.debug('Callout error: '+ e);
        System.debug(res.toString());
    }
        return null;
 
    }
}
```

Here is the test class, which is showing 90% code coverage.

```
//testClasst.apxc
@isTest
public class testClassBt {
    @isTest 
    static void testPostCallout() {
               
        System.Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new TestClass());
         Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();
          opp.Name='Rickson Developer';
          opp.StageName='Underwrite';
          opp.CloseDate= date.newInstance(1991, 2, 21);
          opp.Closing_Date__c= date.newInstance(1991, 2, 21);
          opp.Offer_Acceptance_Date__c =date.newInstance(1991, 2, 21);
          opp.Purchase_Price__c = 1200.00;
          opp.Escrow_Deposit__c= 1200.00;
          opp.Company_Profile__c='RFTA Properties, LLC';
          opp.County_Contract__c='Orange';
          opp.Left_Main__Address_1__c='123 Main Street';
          opp.Escrow_Agent_Name__c='Test Agent';
          opp.Escrow_Address__c='123 Main street';
          opp.Escrow_Number__c='9892132382';
          opp.Inspection_Days__c=34;
          opp.Special_Clauses__c='Test';
         insert opp;
         ApexPages.StandardController standardController = new ApexPages.StandardController(opp);
        DetailButtonController strResp = new DetailButtonController(standardController);

        strResp.doSomething();
    }
}
```

```
//TestClass.apxc

@isTest
global class TestClass implements HttpCalloutMock {
    global HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest request) {
        HttpResponse response = new HttpResponse();
        response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        response.setBody('{"animal": {"id":1, "name":"Tiger"}}');
        response.setStatusCode(200);
        return response;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming that during the validation process you run just the test methods of this class, did you try to run your test class in Sandbox first?

Some IDE and the Salesforce Developer Console itself show you the covered lines after the unit test execution.
Just follow the green lines to debug the code and understand where the exception has been thrown.

If you could post the Test class too, we can help you more.

Comment: I have updated the test class code, Please check and let me know what is wrong in the actual code So that I can fix it.

Comment: Are you trying to deploy the classes with a Change Set?
Are both the Mock class and Test class in the Change Set?

Comment: I tried both with test classes and without test class? When i deployed main file I got 9-10 code coverage and with both test classes i got the validation failed with 0% coverage.

Comment: When you got 0% is because the test method fails.
That means that an exception has been thrown and not at the line "res = http.send(req)" because is in a try/catch.

The exception has been thrown before.
Try to insert some system.debug() statements to debug your code.
Insert a Salesforce Debug Logs too from the Setup of your Production Environment and see what's going on. 

You need to understandand what's the Error Message of the Exception.
If the test class works in sandbox, you are missing something in Prod.
Maybe a customSetting, or a MDT (if you are referencing them in the class)

Comment: Have you looked to see if there is a potential validation rule on opportunity that doesn't exist in your sandbox?